# How to find the count of spaces in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file which has few columns, I need to find no.of spaces in the column values.

Example:

| Key |
| --- |
| Identifier |
| Identifier Number |
| user identifier number |
| user |
| Location of user |

```
  df['count'] =df['Key'].apply(lambda x:x.isspace())
```

Above line is giving True, False values. Can anyone help me how to get the count of no.of spaces in 'key' column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with `\s+` for match spaces:

```
df['count'] =df['Key'].str.count('\s+')
print (df)
                      Key  count
0              Identifier      0
1       Identifier Number      1
2  user identifier number      2
3                    user      0
4        Location of user      2
```